# form handling: "bind" is deprecated in symfony 2.3 - "submit" doesn't work either

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In symfony 2.3 binding a `Request` to a form with `bind()` is **deprecated**:

```
$form->bind($this->getRequest());
```

Now I tried using the `submit()` method instead (as described in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html)):

```
$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));
```

...but it doesn't work.

The form did not change the object that I added to it upon creation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Passing the Request directly to submit() still works, but is
>   deprecated and will be removed in Symfony 3.0. You should use the
>   method **handleRequest()** instead.

( [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html#passing-a-request-to-form-submit-deprecated) )